# When using Areas with MVC2 is it good practice for an area to have its own Content folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, areas

I have an MVC2 application that is divided into Areas. Is it good practice for each area to have its own Content folder for Images, Styles etc that only pertain to that area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having used areas for a while each with its own Content folder for area specific items it seems to work well and we have come across no problems associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly irrespective of your areas, you entire application will have similar look and feel. In that case your content could be shared across areas. In your case if every area gets a different look and feel then you can have content specific to that area. However I am sure you don't have that scenario.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, as I said it would be only for content that was specific to that area. All other common content would be shared.